# Delphi 10.4 interpreting TidBytes TidTCPServer

Tags: delphi, tcpserver

I am aware there are many questions like this, but I can't find the answer to my specific problem.
I want to read the data that is send by a RFID Card-reader.
I have never used type like TidBytes before, and do not know to interpret the specifications,

The specifications are the following :

Event Data

| Fields | Size (Byte) | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Time | 4 | Reserves Data Type |
| Data Size | 1 | The size of the data buffer array (0~16). |
| Data Buffer | 16 | The data buffer array (Card UID or Sector Data). |
| Device Name | 16 | Name (String Type) |
| XID | 4 | Reserves |

With the Help of some demos I can read the data with the following code:

I use the TIdTCPServer.onExecute procedure  :

```
procedure Ttid.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
    
    var
      Buffer : TIdBytes ;
      s: UTF8String;
      i, BufSize: Integer;
    begin

    BufSize := 40;

      if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then begin
    
         if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(1000) then begin
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer,BufSize ,true);
    
          for i := 0 to BufSize do
            s :=s +  IntToStr(buffer[i]);
    
          Memo1.Lines.Add(s) ;
         end;
      end;
    end;
```

the result looks like this :

3 scans :

112205120141481481206200000000000069825553484568101109111000000211231215
1162051201414819136200000000000069825553484568101109111000000211231215
1172051201414819136200000000000069825553484568101109111000000211231215

But using the demo software that ships with the reader, I know the Card ID's (Device Name) should typically look this :

3E03BF94, 3E789494 ...

So, the question is, how do I make the transformation from these numbers tot the 'real' ID's, using the specifications.

any help/hint is very much appreciated !

With the help of Tom Brunberg, I changed the code to :

```
procedure Ttid.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Buffer : TIdBytes ;
  RxBufSize: Integer;
begin

  RxBufSize := 10;

  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then begin

     if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(seTimeout.Value) then begin

      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer,RxBufSize,true);

      Memo1.Lines.Add( IntToHex(buffer[9])
                     + IntToHex(buffer[8])
                     + IntToHex(buffer[7])
                     + IntToHex(buffer[6])
                        );
     end;

  end;

end;
```

the result, scanning 3 cards, is the same Card-ID's the demo-software shows :

3E789494
3E03BF94
3E803194

kind regards,

Dirk Janssens.

Comment: If you would add a comma after each byte translation it would be easier to evaluate the bytes you have received. So, use this: `s :=s +  IntToStr(buffer[i]) + ',';` or alternatively, use `IntToHex()` function. If you convert each of the four bytes of card ID to decimal you will see that the first card id (decimal byte values 62,3,191,148) occurs in reversed byte order for the second and third scan. Converting binary data to strings in hexadecimal or decimal form and vv is a basic skill to master.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpfull,
 I cannot see the arrow for "upvoting" so sorry for using this comment to thank you ...

Comment: You are welcome. Answers in comments can not gain upvotes to gain reputation, so I can only blame myself, for not providing a proper answer ;) Just to satisfy my curiosity, how should the time field be interpreted?

Comment: I do not know that. All I am interested in was a stable and unique ID. so I can process that in my own software. I get timestimps etc in Delphi...

Comment: Please update your question according to Tom Brunberg comment and show the hex representation of the data you receive.

Comment: Thank you Remy for your answer. Very helpful,. There is just one thing: I cannot find "ReadUInt8 " anywehre.
 I am using Delphi 10.4. replacing it with ReadUInt16 gives errors. I am sure the solution must be very simple, but these functions are all new to me...

Answer (score 1):

First off, `TIdTCPServer` is a *multi-threaded* component, its `OnConnect`, `OnDisconnect`, `OnExecute`, and `OnException` events are fired in the context of worker threads created to manage each accepted client connection.  As such, it is not safe to *directly* access UI controls from outside of the main UI thread.  You *must* synchronize access to them, such as with `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Queue()`.

So, the code you have shown would need to look more like this instead:

```pascal
procedure Ttid.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
  s: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, 41);
    
  s := IntToHex(Buffer[0], 2);
  for i := 1 to High(Buffer) do
    s := s + ' ' + IntToHex(Buffer[i], 2);
    
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
    end
  );
end;
```

That being said, there are different ways you can implement that RFID specification with `TIdTCPServer`.  Just note that you have to take into account that the "Data Buffer" field of the RFID data is *variable-length* when reading the bytes (your original code was not accounting for that at all):

- `TIdIOHandler` has many methods for reading various data types, including fixed-sized integers:

```pascal
procedure Ttid.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  iTime, XID: UInt32;
  Data: TIdBytes;
  DeviceName: string;
begin
  with AContext.Connection.IOHandler do
  begin
    iTime := ReadUInt32;
    ReadBytes(Data, ReadUInt8);
    DeviceName := ReadString(16);
    XID := ReadUInt32;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

- Indy's `IdGlobal` unit has similar functions for reading various data types out of a `TIdBytes` buffer:

```pascal
procedure Ttid.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  iTime, XID: UInt32;
  Buffer, Data: TIdBytes;
  DeviceName: string;
  Offset: Integer;
begin
  with AContext.Connection.IOHandler do
  begin
    ReadBytes(Buffer, 5);
    ReadBytes(Buffer, ReadUInt8 + 20, True);
  end;

  SetLength(Data, Length(Buffer)-25);

  Offset := 0;
  iTime := BytesToUInt32(Buffer, Offset);
  Inc(Offset, 4);
  CopyTIdBytes(Buffer, Offset, Data, 0, Length(Data));
  Inc(Offset, Length(Data));
  DeviceName := BytesToString(Buffer, Offset, 16);
  Inc(Offset, 16);
  XID := BytesToUInt32(Buffer, Offset);

  ...
end;
```